# All tangent planes to a surface of revolution (S) at points M of A (intersection of (S) with the plane of equation: z=a) pass by a fixed point.

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm faced with this problem. [The complete problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LOLJ.png)

In part 6, I'm asked to show that all the tangent planes to the surface of revolution (S) at points M of A (which is the intersection of (S) with the plane of equation: z = a) pass by a fixed point to be determined.

Here is what I've tried:

In part 3, I've found that the cartesian equation of (S) is: $x^2z^2 + y^2z^2 = 1$
then in part 6 I tried to find the equation of the tangent plane to (S) at point $M=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ which is:
${\textbf{MX}.{\nabla{F}}}=0$ where $X=(x,y,a)$ but I don't know if this is true.